# Why am I getting a weird number for this question?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Question:

> $2$ sides of a triangle are $4$ units and $5$ units and the difference between the angles opposite to them is $\arccos(\frac{31}{32})$. Let $\Delta$ represent the area of the triangle. Find the value of $\frac{16}{7}\Delta^2$.

I have used cosine rule to determine the sides and then calculated the value of $\frac{16}{7}\Delta^2$. The answer is an integer but I am getting a weird number. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I believe you need to put text from title to post and make another title. And I don't understand what is your reason. Do you want people to check your answer? Then show your result.

Comment: If you show us your work, we may be able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: You seem better at typing than I am, so can you type in your workings?

Comment: let the triangle be ABC and side lens BA 5 and 4        
 cosine rule becomes (41 - a²) / 40 and cos B= (a² + 9 )/10a and cos C =(a²-9)/8a now calculating sinB becomes under root 82a square minus a to the power 4 - 81 / 100 a square and sin C =√((82a²- a - 81)/64a)²cos b - c is equal to 31 by 32 expanding cost b minus c cos b cos c + sin b sin c equal to 31 by 32 after calculating I get cos a equal to 6245 / 6560 now if I go for sinA it's way to complicated ....

Comment: Your comment, Krishna, is almost unreadable, due to the lack of proper formatting of the mathematics. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to see how to format mathematics here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your difficulty seems to be trying to calculate the sines. There is no need to do so, because you can get rid of them.

How?

We let $a=5,b=4,c$ unknown be the sides, and $A,B,C$ be the corresponding angles. You have established that

$\cos(A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B=31/32.$

Now comes the sneaky part. The angles of the triangles add up to $180°$, so each angle is supplementary to the sum of the other two. Thereby

$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B=-\cos C.$

And then just add up your two equations; the sines cancel out:

$2\cos A \cos B=(31/32)-\cos C.$

Now apply the Law of Cosines  to express each of these cosines in terms of the sides, thus

$\cos A=(b^2+c^2-a^2)/(2bc)$

and the appropriate cyclic permutations.

After doing this and putting in $a=5,b=4$ you have an equation you can solve for $c$. Many terms cancel when you clear fractions, multiply polynomials and combine like terms, and you should easily find $c$. With all the sides known you get the area of the triangle with Heron's Formula.

> $c=6,16\Delta^2/7=225.$

Comment: Ok I got it it's just that I am too obsessed to use the sine formula of area of triangle ...